# getting the whole response from HttpClient PostMethod

Tags: java, http-post, httpclient, httpresponse

I connect make a post method like the following :

```
try {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            PostMethod method = new PostMethod(VERIFY_PAYMENT_ACTIONURL);

            // key is the parameter
            // MERCHANT_KEY is the value
            method.addParameter("key", MERCHANT_KEY.trim());
            method.addParameter("command", VERIFY_PAYMENT_COMMAND.trim());
            method.addParameter("hash", hash);
            method.addParameter("var1", transactionID);
            method.addParameter("salt", ALGORIHTM_SHA512_SALT_KEY.trim());

            int statusCode = client.executeMethod(method);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

this works fine and I get `200` as statusCode since the method is success. I would like the get the whole response since I have to do some more functionalities based the response returned.

the response from the server is array like the following :

```
array('status' => '1',
'msg' => 'Transaction Fetched Successfully',
'transaction_details' =>
array(
unknown)
)
);
```

and I will have to get the value `from the response like msg etc`.

so my issues here is how do I retrieve the response object which is returned from the `post call`

would some one help me on this please..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use any of:

```
byte[] data = method.getResponseBody();
String text = method.getResponseBodyAsString();
InputStream is = method.getResponseBodyAsStream();
```

Do not forget to call `method.releaseConnection()` when you have processed the content (especially when you're using `method.getResponseBodyAsStream()`)!

Comment: i use method.getResponseBodyAsString , it print out part of my response , but not the complete one , the response has been cut off ..

Answer (score 3):

Change your `HttpClient` to `org.apache.http.client.HttpClient` interface.

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
..
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(...);
```

Inside response object, you will find what you want.